# Chiang Mai Treks with Barking Gecko

Tags: thailand, trekking, ecotourism, chiang-mai

I am researching eco treks in Chiang Mai and came across [Barking Gecko Travel](http://www.barkinggeckotravel.com/).  They are a trekking company that doesn't use elephants and are TAT (Tourist Authority of Thailand) certified. I can't find any reviews online.  Has anyone ever used them or know of someone who has?

Comment: They claim to operate since 2008 and no comments about it on the internet. I took a look in the lonely planet, but nothing to find.

Answer (score 8):

My wife and I booked through Barking Gecko Travel last January and had a really great experience.  Barking Gecko Travel is operated by Travel Hub, so I think it would be fair to expect reviews about Travel Hub may translate over to Barking Gecko.

The tour guides provided spoke great English and we really felt that we were being taken into the jungle and seeing sights that not very many tourists get to see (we did the 3 day 2 night homestay trek).  Our first night we stayed at a remote homestay in the middle of the jungle near Chang Mai, and the last part of our trek ended with us staying in this Spicy Village Ecolodge for 1 night. Absolutely beautiful place: [chiangmaiecolodges.com](http://www.chiangmaiecolodges.com/). I think our guide's name was Dang... or Dayg. And another guide's name was Samart.

I should also mention that the itinerary is extremely flexible.  If you want to do something, or don't want to do something the guide will cater the trip to whatever you want.  Just make sure at the beginning you outline if you don't want to do something specific.