# Group jungle trek in Chiang Mai

Tags: thailand, trekking, chiang-mai

I'm looking for some 2 or 3-day jungle treks in Chiang Mai (preferably 2 days). Since I'm traveling alone, I would like to join a group and not have a private trek on my own. I already kinda have a plan for an elephant visit (which I trust), so I'd rather have a jungle trip without elephants (except if you know it's one where it's known that the elephants are treated well).

I found some jungle treks like [this barking gecko trek](http://www.barkinggeckotravel.com/BG301-chiang-dao-discovery/BG301-tours-detail-itinerary.html). But the site reads it's private tours only. So any idea which are group jungle treks, instead of private jungle treks? (This is something I'm really looking forward to.)

Comment: [Related question on Barking Gecko treks there](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10888/chiang-mai-treks-with-barking-gecko?rq=1)

Comment: @MarkMayo I know, I've read this post. But Barking Gecko treks are private treks only, I think.

Comment: Asking for `good group jungle treks` renders the question kinda opinion-based. you might want to edit it to avoid closure.

Comment: @JoErNanO I've rephrased it now. However, the question mainly remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of join-in treks offered in Chiang Mai. And unless you are traveling during a peak time (Christmas/New Year or Songkran), you could could wait until you get there to talk with tour companies and form your own opinion before booking.

If you want more feedback before you go, you might try some of the other online forums, such as TripAdvisor or Thorn Tree, as they have more opinion based posts whereas this forum is "facts and only the facts ma'am".

Comment: Since I'm only there for 6-7 days, I was hoping to be able to plan this in advance. Because I'm afraid I won't be able to read reviews or double check if I'll book it there and be let down. But I'll try the forums first.